# How to change node in TreeMenu?

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I have the TreeMenu with some nodes:

```
{
    text: 'Test',
    leaf: true
}
```

I attached a listener on the TreeMenu:

```
listeners: {
  contextmenu: function(node, event) {

    ContextMenu.showAt(event.getXY());
    event.stopEvent();

  }
}
```

But I don't know how to change the node:

```
// HTML don't changed
node.text = 'my value';

// Uncaught TypeError: node.reload is not a function
node.reload();
```

**UPD**

I decided in this way:

```
node.setText('my value');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tree has to have some kind of [store](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.3/api/Ext.data.TreeStore.html) / root ([NodeInterface](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.3/api/Ext.data.NodeInterface.html)). All you have to do is to change the value in the store / root and the tree will be automatically changed.

You should never use `node.text = 'my value'` because in most cases it won't be just simple object. You should use `node.set('text', 'My Text');`

The handler function for change could look something like this:

```
    handler: function() {
        var tree = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('treepanel')[0];
        var child = tree.getRootNode().getChildAt(0);
        child.set('text', 'Chaned text');
    }
```

Check this fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1hc1

I am not sure which exact version of ExtJS are you using? Ext 3 ? More or less the concept should be the same over all Ext versions.